# SQL navigator - "insert into" statement not working on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-insert

One row works fine:

```
insert into maalerverdi.evverdigrenser
(maalepktnr, fradato, tildato, telleverkartnr, minimum, maximum)
values 
(100121, '01-jan-2019', '01-jun-2073', 202, -0.0001, 50)
```

But adding one more row does not work:

```
insert into maalerverdi.evverdigrenser
(maalepktnr, fradato, tildato, telleverkartnr, minimum, maximum)
values 
(100121, '01-jan-2019', '01-jun-2073', 202, -0.0001, 50),
(100126, '01-jan-2019', '01-jun-2073', 202, -0.0001, 50);
```

> Error: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle...? The `insert` syntax varies across databases.

Comment: Performing multiple inserts with `VALUES` is not part of the SQL Standard. You may need to write separate insert statements. However, most database engines support it.

Comment: Have you checked you dbms documentation, whether it support multi-row insert or not???  That's probably should be the first thing you check before posting a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message looks like Oracle's `ORA-00933` (whose message is `SQL command not properly ended`). Indeed, this database (unlike many others) does not support the syntax you are using to insert multiple rows at once.

If you want to do this in a single statement, you can use [the `insert all` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) instead. Its purpose is to `insert` into one or multiple tables, so you need to repeat the table name and column list:

```
insert all 
    into maalerverdi.evverdigrenser
        (maalepktnr, fradato, tildato, telleverkartnr, minimum, maximum)
        values  (100121, '01-jan-2019', '01-jun-2073', 202, -0.0001, 50)
    into maalerverdi.evverdigrenser
        (maalepktnr, fradato, tildato, telleverkartnr, minimum, maximum)
        values  (100126, '01-jan-2019', '01-jun-2073', 202, -0.0001, 50);
```

Side note: you seem to be attempting to insert into `date` columns. If so, I would recommend using the standard syntax to declare date literals rather than this custom format (whether Oracle will successfully interpret it as a date depends on your database and session settings). That would be:

```
insert all 
    into maalerverdi.evverdigrenser
        (maalepktnr, fradato, tildato, telleverkartnr, minimum, maximum)
        values  (100121, date '2019-01-01', date '2073-06-01', 202, -0.0001, 50)
    into maalerverdi.evverdigrenser
        (maalepktnr, fradato, tildato, telleverkartnr, minimum, maximum)
        values  (100126, date '2019-01-01', date '1973-06-01', 202, -0.0001, 50);
```